# Javascript basic math operation not being computed sometimes

Tags: javascript, math

I'm running into a very interesting issue in an implementation in javascript that I'm coding. I have a function called add() that performs a matrix addition if the object passed is an instance of my custom Matrix class, but at different points in the code the same function doesn't compute the result. The function is as follows:

```
add(n) {
    if(n instanceof Matrix) {
        console.log('sum aaa')
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {

                // I broke down the formula to see each output independently
                let a = this.data[i][j]
                let b = n.data[i][j]
                let result = a + b
                this.data[i][j] = result
                console.log('a = ' + a + ' b = ' + b + ' result = ' + result)

                // this is what I had
                //this.data[i][j] += n.data[i][j]
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('sum bbb')
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                this.data[i][j] += n
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here are the outputs of 2 diferent times I call this same function:

[image: results computed correctly]

[image: results not computed at all]

Note how in the first image the desired output is computed, but in the second image it isn't computed at all.

This function is called from a method of a Neural Network I'm building following a youtube tutorial. At first I thought that the problem could be where I was calling the function, but running tests with different scenarios and datasets everything goes is computed as expected, the problem really seems to be in the add() function.

Am I missing something here? Why could this be happening? I have no clue to be honest. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing the addition. Notice that in the second image, all of the `b` values have an "e-28" at the end, which is exponential notation meaning that the b values are incredibly small, basically 0. 
The addition is being done, the `b` values just don't have a noticeable effect on the output in the second example.

Comment: You are right... After a couple of hours looking at numbers trying to figure out what was going on I missed this. Thank you